# Cracks near the tyre tread. Are they concerning?

Tags: tires, maintenance, preventive-maintenance

[image: ODO 48000 KM, Age = 27 months]

The guy at the tyre shop tried to convince me that my tyres need replacement. My car is just above 2 years old and I plan to change them after 3 years. Please have a look at the picture and advise.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on how old they are. You state your vehicle is two years old (or at least I'm assuming that). Your tires could be much older, so you'll have to determine the date code on the tire itself. [Tires should be no older than 10 years, while some manufacturers state six years is the maximum.](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+old+should+tires+be+before+replacment) This *usually* doesn't come into play as tires wear out (due to mileage) well before this time limit occurs.

To read the date code, look at the following image:

[image]

[This website says](https://www.tirebuyer.com/education/how-to-determine-the-age-of-your-tires):

> The date of manufacture is the last four digits of the DOT code. The first two digits are the week of manufacture, and the last two digits are the year. For example, if the last four digits of the DOT code are 0203, that means that the tire was manufactured during the second week of the year 2003.

For the above image, the tire would have been made the 16th week of 2012.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The code (0916) says they were made in  9th Week on 2016. 

My main concern is that I usually go long route i.e. 800+ km every now and then. With a top speed of 140 Km/h ... Kindly advise.

Comment: @AmmarHassan - Considering your tires are about three years old, have plenty of tread, and are (at worst) showing micro cracking, I'd suggest you probably won't have any issue with your tires. The ***best*** thing you can do about your tires is to ensure they are properly inflated. Too low of a pressure and you'll overheat your tire, which will kill them. Over inflate your tires and you risk rupture. Keeping them just right and you should be in good shape! Tires are made to go distances, I'm sure you'll not have any issues. However, there's always a chance something can happen.

Answer (score 2):

Small cracks like those in the picture are, in my experience, normal. Although I can't be certain just by looking at a photo, the tread depth seems pretty OK too, so there should still be enough life left in your tyres - provided they're not too old, as already stated in the answer by Paulster2.